# Java Prepared statement for query using oracle function pivot

Tags: java, jdbc

How do I pass parameters in place of abcd for the following query while using a prepared statement?

```sql
select * from table (PIVOT ( ' select A, B, SUM(C) from TABLE_XYZ where A =' 'abcd' ' GROUP BY A, B ORDER BY A ASC ' )) order by A;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format(<format of your string with format specifiers like %s or %d and etc >,< parameters >)`.
In the case of your query; It can be written:

```
String query = String.format('select * from table (PIVOT ('select A, B, SUM(C) from TABLE_XYZ where A =' %s ' GROUP BY A, B ORDER BY A ASC')) order by A;',  'abcd');
```

As a result, your query will be like this(abcd without quotes):

select * from table (PIVOT ('select A, B, SUM(C) from TABLE_XYZ where A =' abcd ' GROUP BY A, B ORDER BY A ASC')) order by A;

if you want it with quotes, write this code:

```
String query = String.format('select * from table (PIVOT ('select A, B, SUM(C) from TABLE_XYZ where A =' %s ' GROUP BY A, B ORDER BY A ASC')) order by A;',  '\'abcd\'');
```